# $C^{k}_{a}(X) = a \forall X \in \mathbb{N}^{k}$ explanation.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, notation

I was reading about functions in "Discrete Mathematics and its Applications", and in the "Recursive Functions" section I came across initial functions. One of which is the idea of a constant function.

Now I understand the idea of a constant function. A constant function is a kind of function which no matter the domain, will always give the same output. For example the following is a constant function :-

$$f(x) = 9, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$$

But the definition provided in the example in this book, that I could not understand. The definition is as follows :-

---

$$
\text{ For each } k \geq 0 \text{ and each } a \geq 0 \text{ ,the constant function } C^{k}_{a}:\mathbb{N}^{k} \to \mathbb{N} \text{ is defined by the formula } \\
C^{k}_{a}(X) = a \forall X \in \mathbb{N}^{k}
$$

---

Apart from the definition itself, I don't understand the notations $C^{k}_{a}$ and $\mathbb{N}^{k}$. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: it is saying that for every natural number $k$ and for every natural number $a$, for each element  $X$ of $\mathbb{N}^k$ the function $C_a^k$ maps $X$ to $a$. the notation of the function $C_a^k$ provides u with information about the domain of the function, given by $k$, and the output of the function, given by $a$.

Comment: the notation $\mathbb{N}^k$ is notation for the cartesian product of $\mathbb{N}$ with itself $k$ times. it’s elements are $k$-tupples of natural numbers.

Comment: @CSquared Thanks!
I will select this as an answer if you post them as the answer :)

Comment: I will admit that was a very notation heavy way to define a constant function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is saying that for every natural number $k$ and for every natural number $a$, for each element $X$ of $\mathbb{N}^k$ the function $C_k^a$ maps $X$ to $a$. The notation of the function $C_k^a$ provides you with information about the domain of the function, given by $k$, and the output of the function, given by $a$.

The notation $\mathbb{N}^k$ is notation for the cartesian product of $N$ with itself $k$ times. It’s elements are $k$-tupples of natural numbers.